# Remove Row through DataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataadapter

I've initialized a dataAdapter :

```
string sql = "SELECT * From localitati";
da1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
da1.Fill(ds1, "localitati");
```

And this works just fine. The problem is when i try to delete a record and update the database.
I remove a record from the dataset as such :

```
ds1.Tables["localitati"].Rows.Remove(dRow);
```

And this works just fine as well(verified).

The problem is when i update the DataAdapter, the DataBase doesn't get modified :

```
con.Open()
da1.Update(ds1, "localitati");
con.Close();
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you've set the da1.DeleteCommand - this is the command that will be fired for each row in the DataTable that has been deleted. See [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 14):

What fixed it for me was to call the `Delete` method on the `DataRow` instead of the `Remove` method on the `DataTable`.

```
ds.Tables["localitati"].Rows.Find(primaryKeyValue).Delete();
```

or just simply

```
dr.Delete();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The .Delete() method will alert the parent DataTable that the row has been deleted.  Simply removing the row from the table is not enough.

Comment: In my code, I was trying to do Table.Clear(). It was not updating the database after the Update call. However, using Delete did. I agree this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

try below code
 assuming that Database is not throwing any exception.

```
con.Open() 
da1.Update(ds1.Tables["localitati"].GetChanges()); 
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you have posted only the SelectCommand is set for the DataAdapter. 
You could use the following code to generate the Insert, Update and Delete commands for da1.

```
string sql = "SELECT * From localitati";
da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da1);
builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
da1.Fill(ds1, "localitati");
```

The CommandBuilder however should be used only for relatively simple scenarios ([details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971491.aspx)). For he rest is recommended to write your own commands that rely on custom command texts/stored procedures.

If it still doesn't work, you could start a SQL Server Profiler on the server to trace what command gets to the database when you execute the Update method.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow dr = datatable.Rows.Find(key);      
int Index = datatable.Rows.IndexOf(dr);

BindingContext[DataTable].RemoveAt(Index);     
BindingContext[DataTable].EndCurrentEdit(); 

dataAdapter.Update(DataTable);    
DataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Some explanation could be nice