# Why this code doesn't delete specified row in database?

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

I have to use SqlDataAdapter in this issue. Why this code doesn't want to delete a specified row?

There are no errors, script is entering to if statement.

id_book is correct, table name: Book

```
        public static void DeleteBook(int id_book)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbCon.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Book", connection);
                var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                var table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);

                var rowToDelete = table.Select($"id_book = {id_book}").FirstOrDefault();
                if (rowToDelete != null)
                {
                    table.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);
                    adapter.Update(table);
                }
            }
        }
```

DELETE FROM Book WHERE id_book = 20; -> works correctly in DB

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but: using `DataAdapter` and `DataTable` is *very* old school, and should basically not be done for new work unless you have an actual use case with fully dynamic table structures (where `DataTable` still has some defensible use, despite its considerable memory overhead). From a more friendly O-O approach to maintaining entities, check out things like Entity Framework; for lightweight database operations without the overhead of boilerplate, look at things like Dapper.

Comment: @ThomasWeller it does. If it cannot find any -matching elements if you provide a predicate- it will return default value of the type, which is null for any reference type. It would be better to check if the returned value is default. I mean: if (rowToDelete != default)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302052/remove-row-through-dataadapter You have to DELETE rather than REMOVE